# Difference between Darood-Ibrahim and Salam

Tags: sects, darood

There has been a debate in Deobandi and Barelvi about Salat-o-Salam. While Deobandi say it is important to send salam (salat-o-salam) to Prophet Muhammad (PBUH), as He can listen and emphasis of children to join the mosque which sends out salat-o-salam after Namaz. 

I don't know much about Islam as I am coming back towards it but I never heard of Salat-o-Salam or Muhammad (PBUH) Darood being different than Darood Ibrahim, as I thought it was the same.

My question is, is there any different Darood for both prophets and why there is so much difference between deobandi and barailvi. what are the core differences?

Comment: First I strongly recommend you to ask these questions separtly as they indeed are different. However your second question (difference between deobandi and barlaivi) might be too broad ->off-topic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Durood is we pray to Allah for blessings on Prophet (SAW) and Salam is we sent the Greetings directly to our Prophet.
For further assistance, you can read the blog for [difference between Durood-e-Ibrahim and Durood Shareef](https://onlinedurood.com/question/is-durood-shareef-and-durood-ibrahim-the-same/).

Answer (score 1):

A simple and short answer about the difference between Darood and sending salat-o-salam is:

That what you call Darood Ibrahim (or as-salat al-ibrahimiya) is/was what the Prophet () himself taught the sahaba (). So this is the version of praising the Prophet () and his Family which has a backup and a known reward.

Therefore for many scholars this is the first, if not only legal choice to praise him.

While any other way of praising the Prophet () is an invention which came in later centuries or times, and might or might not be rewarded, some would even call it bid'ah. However based on the quran we are asked to send salam to our Prophet () and the quran has not mentioned that this must be in a special wording, so maybe the reward for any other formulation is only known by Allah Himself.

Answer (score -1):

No doubt darood Ibrahimi is darood taught by the Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him. BUT SALAM also should be sent in addition to it.

Comment: Any citation would be helpful.